# An error about listview

Tags: android, listview, filechooser

I tried to make a file choose following the below link
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/

However, I got the error "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' "

I have googled the error and I need to get a listview tag in the xml file. However, the above example does not have it and it seems working well.

Although I am not triggering the file chooser in the main page, I think my code does not have much differences to it. Could you help me to see if there are any ways to solve this problem, please?

file_view.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
<TextView android:id="@+id/fd_text1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"></TextView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/fd_text2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

filechooser.java

```
public class filechooser extends ListActivity{
 private fileArrayAdapter adapter;
 private File curDir;


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.file_view);
  curDir = new File("/sdcard/");
  fill(curDir);
 }

 public void fill(File f){
  File[] dirs = f.listFiles();
  this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
  List<fc_option>dir = new ArrayList<fc_option>();
  List<fc_option>fls = new ArrayList<fc_option>();
  try{
   for (File ff: dirs){
    if (ff.isDirectory())
     dir.add(new fc_option(ff.getName(), "Folder", ff.getAbsolutePath()));
    else
     fls.add(new fc_option(ff.getName(), "File Size: " + ff.length(), ff.getAbsolutePath()));
   }

  }catch (Exception e){

  }

  Collections.sort(dir);
  Collections.sort(fls);
  dir.addAll(fls);
  if (!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
   dir.add(0,new fc_option("..","Parent Directory", f.getParent()));

  adapter = new fileArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.file_view, dir); //get problems
  this.setListAdapter(adapter);

 }

 //@Override 
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
  super.onListItemClick(l,v,position, id);
  fc_option o = adapter.getItem(position);
  if (o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("folder") || o.getData().equalsIgnoreCase("parent directory")){
   curDir = new File(o.getPath());
   fill(curDir);
  }else{
   onFileClick(o);
  }
 }

 private void onFileClick(fc_option o){
  Toast.makeText(this,"File Click"+o.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

the fileArrayAdapter is exactly the same as the link.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is to blame:

```
setContentView(R.layout.file_view);
```

The file_view.xml is the layout for each item in the list, not the layout of the list itself. Since you are overriding a ListActivity, you don't have to set the view, so just removing the above line will do.

Comment: No, its not the layout file for only the items. Since its set by setContentView, it defines the whole layout.

Comment: In the article you've linked there is no setContentView in the OnCreate of the ListActivity. The author uses the file_view.xml as the layout of each individual item and not as the layout of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Updates:

Since your class is extending the ListActivity, it must have a ListView. But as I can see from your layout file (file_view), it lacks one. So add a ListView in your layout file and set its id attribute to "@android:id/list".